# Pandas: how select row based on string in previous row - should be a simple solution

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a a csv file.  How do I print the row that follows a row that has a particular string?  I need to print all rows that contain "ixation" in them and then the row that follows this row.

Here is my current code

```
df = pd.read_csv('locationof.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Trial', 'Code','Time','Duration'])
list1 = ['100_1to3_start','fixation','Fixation','66_1to3_start']
contain_values = df[df['Code'].str.contains('|'.join(list1), na=False)]
```

Here is my current output...

```
2      1.0                fixation_dummy    50637.0   25086.0
4      2.0                fixation_dummy    75889.0   25086.0
7      3.0                fixation_dummy   101141.0   25086.0
9      4.0                fixation_dummy   126393.0   25086.0
13     6.0  100_1to3_start_2034_1_0_1060   151811.0   20268.0
23     9.0  100_1to3_start_2456_4_0_2054   216104.0   24587.0
33    12.0  100_1to3_start_1507_7_0_2446   283885.0   15118.0
43    15.0                      Fixation   332229.0  130081.0
55    17.0   66_1to3_start_2369_2_0_2352   484904.0   23590.0
76    23.0   66_1to3_start_1539_8_0_2518   615150.0   15285.0
82    25.0                      Fixation   654357.0  130081.0
123   35.0                      Fixation   996089.0  130081.0
164   45.0                      Fixation  1343635.0  130081.0
174   46.0   66_1to3_start_1884_1_0_2537  1473882.0   18773.0
197   53.0   66_1to3_start_1541_8_0_2545  1621074.0   15284.0
204   55.0                      Fixation  1662939.0  130080.0
213   56.0  100_1to3_start_2115_1_0_2528  1793186.0   21098.0
223   59.0  100_1to3_start_1892_4_0_2544  1859638.0   18939.0
233   62.0  100_1to3_start_2315_7_0_2537  1918282.0   23259.0
```

But I want...

```
2      1.0                fixation_dummy    50637.0   25086.0
4      2.0                fixation_dummy    75889.0   25086.0
7      3.0                fixation_dummy   101141.0   25086.0
9      4.0                fixation_dummy   126393.0   25086.0
13     6.0  100_1to3_start_2034_1_0_1060   151811.0   20268.0
43    15.0                      Fixation   332229.0  130081.0
55    17.0   66_1to3_start_2369_2_0_2352   484904.0   23590.0
82    25.0                      Fixation   654357.0  130081.0
123   35.0                      Fixation   996089.0  130081.0
164   45.0                      Fixation  1343635.0  130081.0
174   46.0   66_1to3_start_1884_1_0_2537  1473882.0   18773.0
204   55.0                      Fixation  1662939.0  130080.0
213   56.0  100_1to3_start_2115_1_0_2528  1793186.0   21098.0
```

How do I only print out the lines 66_1to3.., 100_1to3...) that follow only a row with "ixation" in it?  This code will be run over a series of csv files in which the exact lines that I need vary between csv files.

Comment: In your example, do you want to print only rows with index 13, 55, 174 and 213?

Comment: Not always, the actual index rows are going to change between csv files for each participant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer this description: "*I need to print all rows that contain "ixation" in them and then the row that follows this row.*", the solution would be:

```
# identify rows with "ixation"
mask = df['Code'].str.contains('ixation')

# select them and one row below
out = df[mask|mask.shift()]
```

Comment: 1) first created a smaller csv file that contained only rows with "fixation" and the rows that had  "100_1to3_start" and "66_1to3_start_" - this removed some of the non-needed rows before I applied @mozway's solution (I mentioned this above)... , `list1 = ['100_1to3_start','fixation','Fixation',]
short_list=df[df['Code'].str.contains('|'.join(list1), na=False)]`, 2) then I added @mozway code above here to only include files that followed the "ixation" rows.  mask = `short_list['Code'].str.contains('ixation')
# select them and one row below
out = short_list[mask|mask.shift()]
print(out)`

Answer (score 1):

Try boolean indexing with `shift` since we only care about the rows that follow "ixation"

```
list1 = ['100_1to3_start', '66_1to3_start']
df[df[2].str.contains('|'.join(list1), na=False) & df[2].shift().str.contains('ixation')]

      0     1                             2          3        4
4    13   6.0  100_1to3_start_2034_1_0_1060   151811.0  20268.0
8    55  17.0   66_1to3_start_2369_2_0_2352   484904.0  23590.0
13  174  46.0   66_1to3_start_1884_1_0_2537  1473882.0  18773.0
16  213  56.0  100_1to3_start_2115_1_0_2528  1793186.0  21098.0
```

Note that `df[2]`, based on your example, would be `df['Code']`

Comment: That isn't exactly what I need, when I type the following code, I get the full csv file... not sure if I am missing something here....

Comment: `df[df[2].str.contains('|'.join(list1), na=False) & df[2].shift().str.contains('ixation')]` is not assigned to a variable. Either assign it to a variable or print it `print(df[df[2].str.contains('|'.join(list1), na=False) & df[2].shift().str.contains('ixation')])` You are just doing `display(df)` which will display the full df the the filtered df.

Comment: @brainimaging_new_to_unix include the output you need in the question. It is fair to say we are not magicians to know exactly what you expect. Once you show the expected output then the necessary code to arrive at it will be provided

Comment: This is now not output anything.  Does shift() allow you to move back a row or does this only work on columns? ,  `print(df[df['Code'].str.contains('|'.join(list1), na=False) & df['Code'].shift().str.contains('ixation')])`   - I have also tried, 'shift(-1) and assigning the whole thing to a variable.  Sorry and thanks @It_is_Chris - I am probably missing something here

Comment: @onyambu editing the question to include output needed.